# Porting gsprint call to Linux

Tags: mono, ghostscript

I have Windows-only code that uses [gsprint](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/gsprint.htm) to print pdf to windows code

What is the best bay to migrate this code to Linux platform?

Comment: strip it from Windows-only code.

Comment: what is the best way to print pdf file on linux printer (Ubuntu)?

Comment: `lpr -P "MyPrinterName" filename.pdf`

Comment: how can I list all printer names (for parameter `-P`)?

Comment: Solved: http://superuser.com/a/177461/168824

Comment: for some PDF files (version `1.7`) lpr does not works

Comment: Trying to solve problem with converting to `pcl`